# What are the differences between PT Sans and Open Sans?

Tags: typography, font-pairing

I was reading this article from http://evolempirecreative.com/font-pairing-web-design/ and came across the PT Sans and Open Sans pairing. Since they are fonts from the same classification (both sans serif), they would be harder to put to work together. I have found just two differences between them which are:

- Double story g versus one story g
- Vertical terminal e's versus angled e's

Are there anymore differences between them? Are those enough for a successful pairing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are very similar typefaces. There are a few differences that make PT Sans more suitable for headings and Open Sans more suitable for body text however.

Open Sans has a larger x-height, larger counters, glyph widths are wider, and overall spacing is more generally open—all things which help with legibility and readability at smaller sizes and for longer passages of text.

PT Sans is narrower, has a smaller x-height, slightly more detail and decoration (angled terminals as you already mentioned and a more decorative tail on the capital Q, for example). There are subtle differences in form, stroke width and stress that make it more appealing at larger sizes too (but that's mostly just my opinion).

> [image]

Open Sans also has many more weights available which makes it more versatile.

> [image]

You can see the differences much clearer by comparing each as a heading & body pair (you can do this easily on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans), since both are available there).

> [image]